# Send batch info to com port?

Tags: serial

I'm trying yo get a .bat file to send my cpu data to the com port my arduino is on. I've tried multiple google results (including one from this site) and everything I found will just... erase all the variable tied to the com port. The arduino is hooked up to an lcd (not really because arduino microview, but basically that) which displays the variables I want and works as expected when I put the data into the serial monitor manually, but when I run anything that's supposed to send the info they all go blank when I have nothing in my sketch that clears them.

The file is getting the data how it should. If I run this

`wmic /namespace:\\root\wmi PATH MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature get CurrentTemperature`

then I get the temperature as normal. But If I try to send that to the com port...

`wmic /namespace:\\root\wmi PATH MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature get CurrentTemperature > COM3`

The arduino reads whatever it's getting as literally nothing and blanks the variables.

Comment: download and install com0com from https://sourceforge.net/projects/com0com/ ... that will create two linked virtual serial ports ... connect a serial monitor, such as PuTTy, or arduino IDE console to one port ... send the WMIC output to the other port ... see what is being sent from WMIC

Comment: what is your specific question? ... you have not provided any information that could be used to debug the problem

Comment: The problem is that the batch file sends literally nothing (to the point where the arduino sets its variables to nothing, not even "0", just nothing) the moment I run the .bat file, even though when I just request the info normally it gives me the correct value.

Comment: (@jsotola see above, forgot to reply)

Comment: The Arduino may be resetting itself each time you open the serial port.

Comment: The variables cannot be blanked. They always have a value. Do you know what exactly the wmic command sends in what format? This sounds like your Arduino code expects one format (like ASCII formatted text in a specific form) but the command sends in a different format. You need to make sure that the wmic command is sending exactly what you expect from it.

Answer (score 0):

As Edgar has noted in the comments the Arduino resets every time you open the serial port.

Every time you perform a redirect the serial port is opened afresh, which resets the Arduino into the bootloader. There is then a brief delay while the bootloader looks for suitable communication for uploading new code, and then your existing program gets started afresh.

Coupled with that is the problem of baud rate: you need to ensure that the serial port is configured for the same baud rate as your program is expecting.

All together that means that a simple redirect like you are using is really not the best way of communicating with an Arduino. Instead you will need to write a proper program that opens the serial port, waits for the Arduino to reset, then starts periodically probing for and sending the information that you need it to.

Python and PySerial is a common choice for beginners as is easy to get started with and has plenty of examples.